# awk strips percent sign, adds extra character when run from windows batch

Tags: batch-file, awk

I trie to do some tool, and it wont work. Wen i write the string direct in CMD it works.

Here is my code:

```
copy *.txt tmp.txt
gawk -F "\"*,\"*" "{print $1,$15}" tmp.txt > tmp1.txt
gawk "NR%2==0" tmp1.txt > turbo.txt
```

http://i41.tinypic.com/dzun7p.png

Comment: batch files use `%` as variable 'markers'. Did you try escaping like `"NR\%2==0"` ? probably won't work either. So put each awk cmd in a file and call like `gawk -f cmd1.awk tmp1.txt > turbo.txt`. Better yet, it looks like you're trying to work around a problem with CSV data, reexport data as tab-separated values and simplify your life ; -) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not combine the two `awk` calls into a single:

```
gawk -f ext.awk tmp.txt > turbo.txt
```

where `ext.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\"*,\"*"
}
NR % 2 == 0 {
    print $1,$15
}
```